# Text property of IWebElement is returning empty string after sending keys

Tags: c#, selenium

I am developing a library for automation testers. I have written a method for send keys and after sending keys, I want to verify that weather text content set properly or not.

```
public void SetValue(IWebelement element, string value)
{
   element.SendKeys(value);
   if(element.Text!=value)
      throw new Exception("Failed to set value.");
}
```

In above snippet always I am getting exception. Is there any solution for doing synchronization without searching element again in DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SendKeys` doesn't change the DOM, so the WebElement doesn't have text you can get using `Text` property. However you can get using

```
element.GetAttribute("value")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get element again to check if text is added. Web browser and your driver object may not be in sync. So again create object of same element and check text.

```
public void CallingFunction(){
IWebElement el1= driver.FindElement(.....)// find control
SetValue(el1, value);
el1= driver.FindElement(.....)// find control again
CheckValue(el1, value)
}

public void SetValue(IWebelement element, string value)
{
   element.SendKeys(value);
}

public void SetValue(IWebelement element, string value)
{
   if(element.Text!=value)
      throw new Exception("Failed to set value.");
}
```